# Academic Help - 4 year College transfer

Tags: united-states, computer-science, degree, bachelor, community-college

I’m aiming for a BA degree. Basically, I’m taking classes for a AS degree in Computer science and AA, but now I’m nervous since I don’t know the answer for: will both of my AS degrees transfer to a 4? Should I just focus on a AA degree? Am I losing time and money? Especially since I’m going to have 2 AS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Many community colleges have agreements with state-run 4-year colleges so that most, if not all, credits are fully transferred. The people who can answer this question are at the "transfer student" office located at the campus you are looking to transfer into, not the community college where you study now. If they don't have a credit transfer agreement with the community college, they can tell you which classes will transfer and which will not. That way you can take the classes that count both for your AS and later the BS.

Answer (score -1):

This question would be best directed to your academic advisor or equivalent office at your particular institution as they would be able to provide specific advice on developing your path through academia and what specific degrees you would like to pursue.